# get html object by tag class in C# razor

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I don't know if this is possible but I want to get an HTML object by class tag in my razor code

```
if (IsPost)
{
    @switch (/*Here comes the code to get the parent id of object with class "active"*/)
    {
        case "tab1":
            if (Request.Form["submitButtonNext"] != null)
            {
            <text>
                //Here comes my code
            </text>
            }
            break;
        case "tab2":
            break;
        case "tab3":
            break;
    }
}
```

This is in my HTML Code

```
<ul id="selector" class="select">
    <li id="tab1">
        <a class="active">some1</a>
    </li>
    <li id="tab2">
        <a>some2</a>
    </li>
    <li id="tab3">
        <a>some3</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

In my razor code "@section Scripts{}" I'm performing some code to change the class name of objects

Comment: This issue sounds more suited to a JavaScript solution rather than Razor syntax. Is there a particular reason you need to do this with Razor?

Comment: Yes, I think honestly is the main idea because after generating a postback I have to get the Request.Form to detect which form input was fired